# How to capture the checkbox options in a custom dialog?

Tags: android, dialog

[image: dialog screenshot]

**My aim**  
I've made a custom dialog composed of a scrollable list view on top and an "OK" button at the bottom. For each row in the list view I've put a checkbox and I wish to capture the checkboxes that are selected when "OK" is clicked.

**Problem**  
After checking out some tutorials online as well as some Q&A here, I've come up with a basic approach. What I did is 
1. in the adapter for the list view, I attach the option name to each checkbox by setTag() when it is created
2. set up an onCheckedChangeListener in the adapter that puts the checked option into an array or remove the option if it's deselected
3. in the onCreateDialog within the main UI activity attach an OnClickListener to the "OK" button and make it retrieve the options array (obtained in step 2) from the adapter.

It works in the end; but I think it's too much trouble and not elegant. I thought about using onItemClickListener for the list view or putting a custom view into an AlertDialog (which offers better button/checkbox management), but gave up after some trials.

Is there anyone who can think of a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed a fairly complex dialog and I ended up writing it as a widget that extends RelativeLayout. When my calendar icon is clicked, it starts an activity which uses the widget, populates days in a calendar, depending on content from a database:

[image: Calendar Widget]

When you extend a layout, you have complete control over how it sizes itself, layout and what it draws on the canvas.
The activity implements OnTouchListener to pick up which date on the calendar has been touched - I'm sure the same could apply to adding images and picking up which checkboxes had been selected.

Answer (score 0):

read about alertdialog with multichoice mode.

Comment: Yes, I've read that before. But I guess in that mode you can only put text on the left? I need to put a picture down somewhere in the list as an option though